# Definition of Boundary Points

Tags: general-topology

Is this definition of boundary points correct?

The point $x$ is said to be a boundary point or a frontier point of the set $M$ if it is not an interior point either of $M$ or of $M^c$ the complement of $M$.

Comment: I think the better definition is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78873/precise-definition-of-the-boundary-set?rq=1)

Comment: I know about this definition and if you think about it they are the same thing, but I wanted to define boundary points without referring to open balls

Comment: Then your task is to demonstrate the two definitions are equivalent, @Tarek.

Comment: @TarekAcila - replace "open ball" with "open set", and the definition suddenly applies to any topological space.